# ODBC xlsx driver connectionstring without header

Tags: excel, odbc, connection-string

I am connecting to **xlsx** files via **ODBC** with following command:

```
"DRIVER=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb);HDR=YES;IMEX=1;READONLY=TRUE;DBQ=C:\Temp\test.xlsx"
```

It works fine but I am always missing one line when there is no header in the file.
Obviously it's because of the parameter **"HDR=YES"** but I cant figure out how to disable the header line.

I have tried **"HDR=NO"** and leaving this parameter out
but no effect.
I can access to the file but I always lose the first line.

Can somebody help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research.

If you open a **XLS** or **XLSX** file via a driver like

```
"DRIVER=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb);HDR=YES;IMEX=1;READONLY=TRUE;DBQ=C:\Temp\test.xlsx"
```

the driver is ignoring parameters completly.
So **"HDR=NO"** has no effect.

Apparently the driver uses a setting in the registry to determine if the first line should be interpreted as an header line.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel
```

So if you set **FirstRowHasNames=00** the first line wont be skipped.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)